# How to remove default android action bar after setting custom action bar view

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Hi all I have one problem
I am trying to move action bar app icon,title,menu or... from left to right
and I am using SherlockActionBar with setCustomView see codes
my activity

```
    private void BiftorSetUpActionBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    View actionbarview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.biftor_action_bar, null);

    View app_actionbar_bg =(View) actionbarview.findViewById(R.id.app_actionbar_bg);

    app_actionbar_bg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bg_normal);
    BiftorApptitle=(TextView) actionbarview.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
    BiftorAppIcon=(ImageView) actionbarview.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
    BiftorAppIcon.setClickable(true);
    BiftorAppMenu=(ImageView) actionbarview.findViewById(R.id.app_menu);
    BiftorAppIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT))
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            else
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);


        }
    });

    BiftorAppMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
    });


    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionbarview);
}
```

my action bar layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/app_actionbar_bg"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal"

     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/app_menu"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffeeeeee"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

all things is OK but I have one problem,when my app launch the original (default) android action bar will load for 2-3 seconds then my custom action bar will show.
I don't want it,I want remove the original completely.

look at this video you will get what I am saying

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgX5k-LzDMM)

I am waiting.
Thanks All

**edit 1:**

I changed some things by searching on Google and this site  but still first default action bar first then load my custom action bar

private void BiftorSetUpActionBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
//getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View actionbarview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.biftor_action_bar, null);
View app_actionbar_bg =(View) actionbarview.findViewById(R.id.app_actionbar_bg);
app_actionbar_bg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bg_normal);

  .
  .
  .
  .Skip....
  .
  .
  .

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionbarview);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);}
```

and changed the style.xml

```
   <style name="BiftorAppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/list_item_bg_normal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/list_item_bg_normal</item>
    </style>
```

but again nothings :-(

Comment: nothings???hey all check my question I need some helps

Comment: I am wondering no anybody know this?

Comment: Have you set the your custom theme in Androidmanifest ?. if yes then it will show whatever you have specified in custom theme.. and note that this custom theme should be in **themes.xml** under 'res' and not in **style.xml**.

Comment: thanks mate, @IchigoKurosaki yes my custom theme working well but dont know why the action bar not work did you see video?tha first old android action bar after 2-3 seconds load my custom action bar

Comment: no any solution?I set the bg of action bar from style and removed this 'View app_actionbar_bg =(View) actionbarview.findViewById(R.id.app_actionbar_bg);
app_actionbar_bg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_bg_normal);'this from java for sure to know the style theme working and that working well but first load old one after some seconds load my custom action bar :-(   @IchigoKurosaki

Answer (score 0):

In a fragment you can do this:

```
 ActionBar actionbar =  ((MainActivity)requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
  actionbar.setDisplayOptions(actionbar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.app_bar_custom_layout);
```