# Customizing action bar in android shows default action bar first

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am new to android, while customizing action bar i noticed that first it shows old(default) action bar first then it shows customized action bar. Also I want to set text color for action bar title. 
My code snippet is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    MenuItem searchItem;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

        ab.setTitle("Modification"); ab.setIcon(R.drawable.ap);
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new
        ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00AA00")));
        ab.setSubtitle("Modification");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I think there must be some silly mistake.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one..
create a theme.xml as follows

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
</style>
<!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#5477B1</item>
</style>
```

Then in your Androidmanifest.xml
mention this in **application** tag

```
<application
  ..
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

Good luck

Comment: @Ichigo Kurosaki

Hi all I have same problem see here can you please check here
http://stackoverflow.com/q/26716029/3255471

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
```

or
Create a style for the action bar and use a custom background:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
    </style>
    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/split_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hello, We have tried your method but this has not resolved my issue. Kindly provide us some alternate method to fix this issue.

Comment: @Moradiya Akash

Hi all I have same problem see here can you please check here
http://stackoverflow.com/q/26716029/3255471